# Can I use data query in ejs inside html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

```
  <% tag.forEach(function(tag) { %>
    <div class="badge bg-primary" style="color: <%=tag.fontcolor%>"><%= tag.name %> 
    <button class="deleteTag" data-id="<%=tag.id%>">X</button></div>
  <% }) %>
```

I want to use `tag.fontcolor` for div style color
but I have problem which appears in this next image:

[property value expectedcss(css-propertyvalueexpected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJqYr.png)

If you can give me a hint on how to solve this problem, that would be grateful.

Comment: What tool is reporting that error message? Are you just using an EJS-unaware CSS syntax checker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in EJS templating, for what is not text (attributes, class, ...), use the tag `<%-` instead of `<%=`

Comment: Attribute values, including class names, **are** text and **should** be escaped.

Comment: i still dont understand.....can you show me example...??

Comment: show me the value of `tag.fontcolor`